# Separating the settings.py data out

Tags: python, django

In my Django project.

I have a requirement of `settings.py`:

in my `settings.py`, there is a `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` variable:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://10.10.10.102',
    'http://10.10.10.102:8000',  
    'http://10.10.10.102:8080',  
    'http://10.10.10.102:8081',
    'http://10.10.10.102:8888',

    'http://10.10.10.103',
    'http://10.10.10.103:8000',
    'http://10.10.10.103:8080',
    'http://10.10.10.103:8081',
    'http://10.10.10.103:8888',
    .....
```

I want to set it flexibly, I mean I can in my user interface for add/update/delete the items.

but it is settings up in `settings.py`, how can I implements my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box django does not support changing settings dynamically, but you can achieve it by using [django constance plugin](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance).